# Need help figuring out hasPermission function

Tags: php, arrays, permissions

I am trying to utilize my hasPermission function that is in my user class, so that I can do different things with users on my site.

I have different permissions of my site in a db table called 'groups'. I have five different group levels. So on some pages of my site I would like to allow the higher end users with higher permission levels to see certain things that others can't.

I'm having issues reading the following code for all this and really figuring out how I can maximize the function and use it for it's purpose other than when someone registers they are assigned to group level 1.

User class

```
public function hasPermission($key) {
    $group = $this->_db->get('groups', array('id', '=', $this->data()->group));

    if($group->count()) {
        $permissions = json_decode($group->first()->permissions, true);

        if($permissions[$key] == true) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

DB class

```
public function insert($table, $fields = array()) {
    $keys = array_keys($fields);
    $values = '';
    $x = 1;

    foreach($fields as $field) {
        $values .= '?';
        if($x < count($fields)) {
            $values .= ', ';
        }
        $x++;
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} (`" . implode('`, `', $keys) . "`) Values ({$values})";

    return ! $this-> query($sql, $fields)->error(); 
}
```

I want to use it so I can give users the ability to see certain things or go on certain pages and if they aren't in the group level I want them to be they would be kicked back to the previous pages. Things like that and I'm sure I can do that with this code, I just don't fully understand it by just looking at it.

I have done this on parts of my site:

```
<?php

if($user->hasPermission('creator')) {
        echo '<p>All access!<p>';
    } else {
        die;
    }
?>
```

That I can say messages to users with certain permissions.

Could someone please explain that code to me and give me a general idea of how to utilize it.

Comment: $group->first()->permissions should have 'creator' value. Then your code works!